# glGetAttribLocation is causing invalid operation

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, glsl, pyopengl

I was trying to make a model/simulation of the moon using python by pyopengl and pygame. I used an open source 3d model of the moon in .obj file and tried to merge it in my code. But for some reason, an error occurs with a tag of

> OpenGL.error.GLError: GLError(err = 1282,description = b'invalid
>   operation',baseOperation = glGetAttribLocation,cArguments = (6,
>   b'position\x00')

My implementation is separated into different classes (like OOP) but the main ones i.e the shader, the moon class and the class where i use that program are listed below. The OBJ loader is directly from the official pygame website.

Vertex Shader

```
#version 330
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 newColor;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 verTexCoord;
out vec3 color;
out vec2 fragTexCoord;
// other methods like scaling, rotation
void main(){
    vec4 pos = vec4(position, 1.0);
    // apply translation, rotation and scaling 
    gl_Position = pos;
    fragTexCoord = verTexCoord;
    color = newColor;
}
```

Fragment Shader

```
#version 330
in vec3 color;
in vec2 fragCoord;
out vec4 outColor;
uniform sampler2D ourTexture;
void main(){
    outColor = texture2D(ourTexture, fragCoord);
}
```

Moon

```
from objloader import *
class Moon(Shape):
    def __init__(self):
        Shape.__init__(self)
        self.obj = OBJ("Moon\moon.obj", swapyz=True)
        self.drawing_type = GL_POLYGON
        self.setup_shaders()
        self.setup_buffers()
    def setup_shaders(self):
        # Get and Compile the shaders here
        self.program = glCreateProgram()
        glAttachShader(self.program, vertexShader)
        glAttachShader(self.program, fragmentShader)
        glLinkProgram(self.program)

    def setup_buffers(self):
        self.vao = glGenVertexArrays(1)
        self.vbo = glGenBuffers(1)
        v = []
        # buildlist will give a list that contains the moons vertices including the texture coordinates. 
        v = self.buildList(self.obj)
        self.vertexes = np.stack(v)
        self.vertex_length = len(self.vertexes)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vertexes.nbytes, self.vertexes, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
        glBindVertexArray(self.vao)
        # This is the line the error occurs at.
        positionLocation = glGetAttribLocation(self.program, "position")
```

Not necessary but here is the Shape class and the function where the drawing text place(It is in a different class than Shape).

```
class Shape():
    def __init__(self):
        self.vao = None
        self.vbo = None
        self.program = None
        self.vertexes = None
        self.drawing_type = None
        self.vertex_length = None
```

Drawing Function

```
def draw(self):
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    for shape in self.shapes:
        glUseProgram(shape.program)
        glBindVertexArray(shape.vao)
        glDrawArrays(shape.drawing_type, 0, shape.vertex_length)
        glBindVertexArray(0)
```

Comment: Why are you querying an attribute location that you explicitly set in the shader? You *know* the answer is going to be 0, so why are you asking?

Comment: I could. The remainder of the code that I omitted is huge. I wanted it to make my code reusable for when I set the glVertexAttribPointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`glGetAttribLocation`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetAttribLocation.xhtml) gives an  invalid operation  error, because the program object `self.program` is not linked correctly.

The program is not linked, because the output variables of the vertex shader does not match the input variables of the fragment shader.

Vertex shader:

```
out vec3 color;
out vec2 fragTexCoord;
```

Fragment shader:

```
in vec3 color;
in vec2 fragCoord;
```

Change the fragment shader like this, to solve the issue:

```
#version 330

in vec3 color;
in vec2 fragTexCoord; // "fragTexCoord" insted of "fragCoord"

out vec4 outColor;
uniform sampler2D ourTexture;
void main(){
    outColor = texture2D(ourTexture, fragTexCoord); 
}
```

---

Note, if a program object has been linked successfully can be checked by [`glGetProgramiv( self.program, GL_LINK_STATUS )`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetProgram.xhtml):

```
glLinkProgram( self.program )
if not glGetProgramiv( self.__prog, GL_LINK_STATUS ):
    print( 'link error:' )
    print( glGetProgramInfoLog( self.__prog ) )
```

For the sake of completeness, if a shader object has been compiled successfully can be checked by [`glGetShaderiv( shaderObj, GL_COMPILE_STATUS )`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetShader.xhtml):

```
glCompileShader( shaderObj )
if not glGetShaderiv( shaderObj, GL_COMPILE_STATUS ):
    print( 'compile error:' )
    print( glGetShaderInfoLog( shaderObj ) )
```

Comment: Tnx it fixed it perfectly. How did I miss that? So disappointed.